# AWS Sagemaker Model Error when making Predictor Call

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to make a tensorFlow predictor call but I am getting a ModelError - 502 Bad Gateway. I can't seem to trace back to what is going on in the server that is causing this error. This model was deployed on ml.c4.xlarge instances.

*As requested from comments, here is the code used to deploy the model:*

```
#Import Tensorflow Model
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
sagemaker_model = Model(model_data='s3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/Scikit-keras-NLP-pipeline-examplet/train/example.tar.gz',
                        role=role,
                        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

scikit_learn_inference_model = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model() 

#Build Inference Pipeline
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, 
    role=role, 
    models=[
        scikit_learn_inference_model, 
        sagemaker_model],
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

*For reference: here is the code in a Sagemaker notebook that is using a .csv file saved in S3 to try and make the prediction:*

```
from sagemaker.predictor import json_serializer, csv_serializer, json_deserializer, RealTimePredictor
from sagemaker.content_types import CONTENT_TYPE_CSV, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON

predictor = RealTimePredictor(
    endpoint='example',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    serializer=csv_serializer,
    content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_CSV,
    accept=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON)

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Binarizer, StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']
dff = pd.read_csv('housing.csv',delimiter=r"\s+", names=column_names)
dff.drop('MEDV',axis=1,inplace=True)

#String
x = '0.00632,18.0,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98'

#DataFrame
y= dff.head(1)

#Array
z = np.array([[0.00632,18.0,2.31,0,0.538,6.575,65.2,4.09,1,296.0,15.3,396.9,4.98]])

print(predictor.predict(z))
```

*Here is the full error for reference:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-1a95d0a95a02> in <module>()
----> 1 print(predictor.predict(z))

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model)
    108 
    109         request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args, target_model)
--> 110         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    111         return self._handle_response(response)
    112 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    314                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    315             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 316             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    317 
    318         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    624             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    625             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 626             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    627         else:
    628             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (502) from container-2 with message "<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

*Finally, a snippet from the CloudWatch Logs if this helps:*

```
2020/07/21 06:31:23 [error] 33#33: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.0.3, server: , request: "POST /invocations HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/v1/models/Servo:predict", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:22001/v1/models/Servo:predict", host: "container-2.aws.local:9553"
```

Comment: Can you add more information on how the model was deployed? Did you use the TensorFlow serving container or did you modify it before deploying?

Comment: @YoavZimmerman Yes, I added the bit of code to the question (first section of code). I deployed it as an inference pipeline using a tensorflow model and scikit_learn_inference_model

Comment: I see. A few ideas on what to try next: 1) Can you serve the model outside of SageMaker using TensorFlow Serving on your local computer? 2) Do these models work independently of each other? e.g. if you remove PipelineModel, will each model work correctly on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke/Deploy with serializer.

```
from sagemaker.serializers import IdentitySerializer
    
sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name=endpoint_name, serializer=IdentitySerializer)
```